# iOS cordova push notification error: no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application

Tags: ios, cordova

I have following error while trying to get device token from APNS

```
did Fail To Register For Remote Notifications With Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3000 "no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application" UserInfo=0x2460a0 {NSLocalizedDescription=no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application}
```

How could i solve it?
Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Testing on a physical device?

Comment: Ahh i think i found the solution.I had removed all the existing key form xcode>>widows>>organiser selected device and removed all the existing provision profile.I downloaded the provision profile with push notification enabled and added to the project and target application in Xcode and it worked.

Comment: Yes I am testing on ios 4 mobile device.